# Trying to count rows in mysql get error java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException:

Tags: java, mysql, relational-database

I'm working my way through a tutorial on jdbc but instead of showing the number of rows it throws th above exception. I've been trying to find the solution but to no avail. Can anyone shed some light on the problem.

```
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs= null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        stmt =conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM states");


        rs.last();
        System.out.println("Number of rows: " +rs.getRow());


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Full stack trace and an indication of which line please.

Comment: Having said that, `SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException` is usually an indication that username or password is wrong - show us `CONN_STRING`, `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` please.

Answer (score 1):

Here exception is not related to fetching size of result set.

Have a look at [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException.html) for SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException:

`This indicates that the authorization credentials presented during connection establishment are not valid.`

And second, to fetch the number of rows in result set, you can use `rs.getFetchSize()` instead of your logic.